# Why does Java use -> instead of => for lambda functions?

Tags: java, lambda

I am a .NET and JavaScript developer. Now I am working in Java, too.
In .NET LINQ and JavaScript arrow functions we have `=>`.

I know Java lambdas are not the same, but they are very similar. Are there any reasons (technical or non technical) that made java choose `->` instead of `=>`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[On September 8, 2011, Brian Goetz of Oracle announced to the OpenJDK mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2011-September/003936.html) that the syntax for lambdas in Java had been mostly decided, but some of the "fine points" like which type of arrow to use were still up in the air:

> This just in: the EG has (mostly) made a decision on syntax.
>
> After considering a number of alternatives, we decided to essentially
> adopt the C# syntax.  We may still deliberate further on the fine points
> (e.g., thin arrow vs fat arrow, special nilary form, etc), and have not
> yet come to a decision on method reference syntax.

[On September 27, 2011, Brian posted another update](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2011-September/004021.html), announcing that the `->` arrow would be used, in preference to C#'s (and the Java prototype's) usage of `=>`:

> Update on syntax: the EG has chosen to stick with the -> form of the
> arrow that the prototype currently uses, rather than adopt the =>.

He goes on to provide some description of the rationale considered by the committee:

> You could think of this in two ways (I'm sure I'll hear both):
>
> - This is much better, as it avoids some really bad interactions with  existing operators, such as:
>
>   ```
>   x => x.age <= 0;                 // duelling arrows
>   ```
>
>   or
>
>   ```
>   Predicate p = x => x.size == 0;  // duelling equals
>   ```
> - What a bunch of idiots we are, in that we claimed the goal of doing  what other languages did, and then made gratuitous changes "just for the sake of doing something different".
>
> Obviously we don't think we're idiots, but everyone can have an opinion :)
>
> In the end, this was viewed as a small tweak to avoid some undesirable
> interactions, while preserving the overall goal of "mostly looks like
> what lambdas look like in other similar languages."

[Howard Lovatt replied](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2011-September/004023.html) in approval of the decision to prefer `->`, writing that he "ha[s] had trouble reading Scala code". [Paul Benedict of Apache](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2011-September/004029.html) concurred:

> I am glad too. Being consistent with other languages is a laudable goal, but
> since programming languages aren't identical, the needs for Java can lead to
> a different conclusion. The fat arrow syntax does look odd; I admit it. So
> in terms of vanity, I am glad to see that punted. The equals character is
> just too strongly associated with assignment and equality.

[Paigan Jadoth](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2011-September/004046.html) chimed in, too:

> I find the "->" much better than "=>". If arrowlings at all instead of the
> more regular "#(){...}" pattern, then something definitely distinct from the
> gte/lte tokens is clearly better. And "because the others do that" has never
> been a good argument, anyway :D.

In summary, then, after considering arguments on both sides, **the committee felt that consistency with other languages (`=>` is used in Scala and C#) was less compelling than clear differentiation from the equality operators, which made `->` win out**.

But [Lieven Lemiengre](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2011-September/004025.html) was skeptical:

> Other languages (such as Scala or Groovy) don't have this problem because
> they support some placeholder syntax.
>
> In reality you don't write "x => x.age <= 0;"
> But this is very common "someList.partition(x => x.age <= 18)" and I agree
> this looks bad. Other languages make this clearer using placeholder syntax
> "someList.partition(_.age <= 18)" or "someList.partition(it.age <= 18)"
> I hope you are considering something like this, these little closures will
> be used a lot!
> (And I don't think replacing '=>' with '->' will help a lot)

Other than Lieven, I didn't see anyone who criticized the choice of `->` and defended `=>` replying  on that mailing list. Of course, as Brian predicted, there were almost certainly opinions on both sides, but ultimately, a choice just has to be made in these types of matters, and the committee made the one they did for the stated reasons.

Comment: This is how different English can be. In my dictionary *to punt* means to travel on a river in a punt. When Paul Benedict said *I am glad to see that punted*, he probably meant *kicked away*.

Comment: I believe your interpretation of Paul's statement is correct, @Ole. But it actually gets worse, as far as English goes. There is a relatively common metaphor (coming from the American football sports game) where "to punt" means "to ignore for now". Technically, it's the same meaning as "kicked away", but it means to avoid making a decision (e.g., because the problem is too intractable and neither option is clearly preferable).

Comment: Thanks, @CodyGray, for providing more background for understanding the expression. It’s certainly informative.